# How to find manually installed program in Linux Mint

Tags: find, software-installation, application

Yesterday I installed Android Studio. I didn't install via the package manager or Software Center. Instead, I downloaded the ZIP package and installed it. After the installation, Android Studio worked fine, although now I can't find it. It's not in my Applications List. How can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `sudo find / -name "studio.*"`.

The way this command works is simple:

- `sudo` runs the find command as superuser (**s**upers**u**ser **do**) so you can check all the directories in the file system including the locked ones.
- `find` searches a given location (`/` in our case) for a given file or directory.
- `/` is the parameter that dictates find where to search (in the whole file system).
- `studio.*` is what to search for ... the wildcard at the end specifies to search for all files that begin with `studio.`. If you wish to make sure you have all possibilities covered, you could run `sudo find / -name "*studio*"`.

Comment: Perhaps `'studio*'`  instead of `studio.sh` ?

Comment: Perhaps, but Android Studio is run from studio.sh

Comment: Although `studio*` can apply to other users, not just this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you know part of the name of a file you installed, e.g. `studio`, you can run

```
locate studio
```

The [`locate` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) finds files whose name contains the specified string. It uses an index which is updated every night (in a typical configuration; the index is updated by a cron job that calls `updatedb` with appropriate parameters), so you won't be able to locate files installed today this way, unless you update the index manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use which:

```
which studio
```

This however does require you to know the full name of the executable